# Finding similar groups in data

Tags: r, clustering

I have a list of stores (3k) and products (300).  I want to group the stores where their range of products is most similar.

So store `a` has 50 products in its range, store `b` has 53 products of which 49 are also in store `a` so their range is almost identical.  Store `c` also has 53 products but only 20 are in store `a` and 15 in store `b` so the range is 'different'

I've initially created a table with store in the rows and products in the columns and filled it with [1,0] where a 1 indicates that products is in that store.

Here is an example in R

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(stores = c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"),
                 p1 = c(1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1),
                 p2 = c(0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1),
                 p3 = c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0),
                 p4 = c(0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1),
                 p5 = c(1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0))
```

In my example I would group up stores `a, b & h` because they both have products 1 and 2 and stores `b & h` only have 1 other product.

Is there a method that can do this programatically in R?

I initially took the pairwise sums of store/products and then took the sum of each column e.g.

```
m <- as.matrix(dt[, c(2:6)])
m <- m %*% t(m)
colSums(m)
```

Doing the column totals makes no sense though because stores `a` and `g` have the lowest values but they are the complete opposite of each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one simple solution, that requires no extra package:

```
rownames(dt)= dt$stores
dt$stores= NULL
D= dist(dt, method= 'binary') #distance matrix
tree= hclust(D) #hierarchical clustering (recoursive aggregation)
clusters= cutree(tree, n) #n= number of clusters
```

Consider that this code uses a method of calculating the distance between stores that's not the only possible one, you should consider other similarity measures (similarity is used in this cases most often than distance), the most popular is Jaccard index. Also hierarchical clustering is not the only clustering method for binary data, but I admit I don't know any other one.

Comment: thanks for the reply. This seems to group the data based on the products but I want the groups to be stores.  Reason being is I want to allocate the products to the stores based on the range that's most similar.
So if stores a,b,& h have the most common products in them, I can simply take the unique list of products between the 3 and then fill the space in the stores with the products where the products are ranked based on £/space.

Comment: that could be, in fact I made some confusion and at first I wrote the code with products on the rows and stores on the columns, but I fixed it before you posted this comment and it should work, grouping stores. `dist(dt)` takes rows to be the units to create distance between of.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what are you trying to say with: "I can simply take the unique list of products between the 3 and then fill the space in the stores with the products where the products are ranked based on £/space"

Comment: yes if I don't transpose the data then it does exactly what I want so thank you!